# How to turn on `read-only-mode` when running a command in `comint` buffers and turn off it when the command is finished?

Tags: hooks, comint, read-only-mode

I'd like to prevent all user inputs when a command is running in `comint`-like buffers (created by `shell`, `run-python` etc.) by enabling `read-only-mode` when I hit enter to run the command and disabling it when the command is finished. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: How will the command write its output to the buffer?

Comment: @NickD I tested, even `read-only-mode` is turn on, the buffer content can modified by the command itself. But user inputs are prevented.

Comment: You are right: `comint-output-filter` is playing around with setting `inhibit-read-only` to t.